# com.google.android.gles_jni.EGLImpl.eglInitialize(Native Method) Error

Tags: android

I know this is VERY long stacktrace. One of my users reported it on the google play market. It is happening with one of my andengine games droid razr to be exact.

I have no clue wha this error is coming from. Ive never seen anything like it..Any one know what this is coming from?

```
 DALVIK THREADS:
    (mutexes: tll=0 tsl=0 tscl=0 ghl=0)
    "main" prio=5 tid=1 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40aab478 self=0x1116910
  | sysTid=22522 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=1074124136
  | schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=24 stm=28 core=1
  at com.google.android.gles_jni.EGLImpl.eglInitialize(Native Method)
  at android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.initializeEgl(HardwareRenderer.java:564)
  at android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.initialize(HardwareRenderer.java:512)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1342)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2558)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4697)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:787)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:554)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

"GLThread 18740" prio=5 tid=18 WAIT
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x41447a30 self=0x1464a30
  | sysTid=22635 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=21384832
  | schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=0
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
  - waiting on <0x41444370> (a android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThreadManager)
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:364)
  at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1444)
  at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1241)

"Thread-18739" prio=5 tid=17 TIMED_WAIT
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x414438e8 self=0x1466908
  | sysTid=22634 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=21392728
  | schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=3 stm=0 core=0
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
  - waiting on <0x4143f218> (a com.google.ads.internal.c)
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:401)
  at com.google.ads.internal.c.run((null):-1)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

"Thread-18738" prio=5 tid=14 SUSPENDED
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x4143eb80 self=0x145f540
  | sysTid=22633 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=21363088
  | schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=1
  at libcore.io.Posix.fsync(Native Method)
  at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.fsync(BlockGuardOs.java:97)
  at java.io.FileDescriptor.sync(FileDescriptor.java:71)
  at android.os.FileUtils.sync(FileUtils.java:111)
  at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.writeToFile(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:592)
  at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.access$800(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:52)
  at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl$2.run(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:506)
  at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.enqueueDiskWrite(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:527)
  at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.access$100(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:52)
  at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl$EditorImpl.commit(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:449)
  at com.google.ads.ag$a.run((null):-1)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

"AsyncTask #1" prio=5 tid=16 WAIT
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x413e8590 self=0x13cb8f0
  | sysTid=22572 nice=10 sched=0/0 cgrp=bg_non_interactive handle=20755136
  | schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=1
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
  - waiting on <0x413e8728> (a java.lang.VMThread) held by tid=16 (AsyncTask #1)
  at java.lang.Thread.parkFor(Thread.java:1231)
  at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:323)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:157)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2022)
  at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:413)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1009)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1069)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

"CookieSyncManager" prio=5 tid=15 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x413e6b58 self=0x13ca628
  | sysTid=22571 nice=10 sched=0/0 cgrp=bg_non_interactive handle=20753016
  | schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=0
  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:118)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:118)
  at android.webkit.WebSyncManager.run(WebSyncManager.java:90)
  at android.webkit.CookieSyncManager.run(CookieSyncManager.java:61)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

"WebViewCoreThread" prio=5 tid=13 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x413e1450 self=0x13bf218
  | sysTid=22556 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=20706920
  | schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=14 stm=17 core=1
  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:118)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:118)
  at android.webkit.WebViewCore$WebCoreThread.run(WebViewCore.java:728)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

"SoundPool" prio=5 tid=12 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x413d6450 self=0x13ab0d8
  | sysTid=22536 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=19211824
  | schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=0
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"d" prio=5 tid=11 WAIT
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x413d60b8 self=0x13aa218
  | sysTid=22538 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=20620904
  | schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=1
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
  - waiting on <0x413d61f0> (a java.lang.VMThread) held by tid=11 (d)
  at java.lang.Thread.parkFor(Thread.java:1231)
  at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:323)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:157)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2022)
  at org.andengine.b.c.d((null):-1)
  at org.andengine.b.a.n((null):-1)
  at org.andengine.b.d.run((null):-1)

"SoundPoolThread" prio=5 tid=10 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x413d6208 self=0x13aa6a8
  | sysTid=22537 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=20619736
  | schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=1
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"Binder Thread #2" prio=5 tid=9 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x413b48b8 self=0x138ad50
  | sysTid=22533 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=20491536
  | schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=1
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"Binder Thread #1" prio=5 tid=8 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x413b4670 self=0x138a2e0
  | sysTid=22532 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=20488864
  | schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=1
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"FinalizerWatchdogDaemon" daemon prio=5 tid=7 WAIT
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x413b1388 self=0x1389970
  | sysTid=22531 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=20471816
  | schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=0
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
  - waiting on <0x40ab2e08> (a java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerWatchdogDaemon)
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:364)
  at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerWatchdogDaemon.run(Daemons.java:213)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

"FinalizerDaemon" daemon prio=5 tid=6 WAIT
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x413b1230 self=0x1389290
  | sysTid=22530 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=20471656
  | schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=0
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
  - waiting on <0x40aa15e8> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue)
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:401)
  at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:102)
  at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:73)
  at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.run(Daemons.java:168)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

"ReferenceQueueDaemon" daemon prio=5 tid=5 WAIT
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x413b10c8 self=0x1388c38
  | sysTid=22529 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=20476080
  | schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=1
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
  - waiting on <0x40aa1510>
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:364)
  at java.lang.Daemons$ReferenceQueueDaemon.run(Daemons.java:128)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

"Compiler" daemon prio=5 tid=4 VMWAIT
  | group="system" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x413b0fd8 self=0x13887e8
  | sysTid=22528 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=20475672
  | schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=5 stm=3 core=1
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"Signal Catcher" daemon prio=5 tid=3 RUNNABLE
  | group="system" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x413b0ee0 self=0x1384358
  | sysTid=22527 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=20481672
  | schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=0
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"GC" daemon prio=5 tid=2 VMWAIT
  | group="system" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x413b0e00 self=0x137e900
  | sysTid=22524 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=20476496
  | schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=1
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```